# Moongose Fetch data from 2 documents

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I would like to get data from 2 different query
for example, in SQL I would do something like

```
select * from user where user_id =(Select ..... )
```

How can I do it in `Moongose`? 
let's say userManager - is my schema
and I want to get the user_id from followingSchema
thanks!

Comment: Your question is not clear. will you please elaborate it to me. Feels lke i am able answer

Comment: @AnkitManchanda hi buddy! tha'ts how i solved it is that good solution?